# The number of nodes in the computational graph in Tensorflow does not make sense

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the following code, I have commented the number of nodes that are added to the computational graph for each line:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()

W = tf.Variable([.3], tf.float32)#4
b = tf.Variable([-.3], tf.float32)#4
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)#1
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)#1
linear_model = W * x + b#2
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(linear_model - y)) # 7
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01) # 0
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)#59
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

But the numbers does not make sense to me. For example, why for a `tf.Variable` line, four nodes are added to the graph? And why for the `optimizer.minimize(loss)`, 59 nodes are added? And whay for `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer` no node is added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because those lines are Python wrappers that translate to several that lower level TensorFlow ops.

Generally, any op that comes from `gen_xxx_ops.py` file like `gen_math_ops.py` will directly translate to a single TensorFlow node (ie, `tf.add`), but things defined in`xxx_ops.py` like `math_ops.py` do some extra Python stuff and can translate to several nodes.

For instance, consider `tf.reduce_sum`. Using `inspect` module or `tf.reduce_sum??` in Jupyter, you can see it's defined in `tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py` with following definition:

```
  return gen_math_ops._sum(
      input_tensor,
      _ReductionDims(input_tensor, axis, reduction_indices),
      keep_dims,
      name=name)
```

The `_sum` call creates a single `Sum` node, but `ReductionDims` also creates TensorFlow nodes defining starting and ending indices for the summation.

If you look at definition of tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer, you'll see that constructor doesn't define any computation, it just saves `lr` parameter. Computation is added on `minimize` or `apply_gradients`.

You can use following helper function to see exactly which nodes were added

```
import tensorflow as tf
from pprint import pprint

tf.reset_default_graph()

with capture_ops() as ops:
    W = tf.Variable([.3], tf.float32)
pprint(ops)
```

Where capture_ops is defined as

```
import contextlib
@contextlib.contextmanager
def capture_ops():
  """Captures any ops added to the tf Graph within this block."""
  from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
  old_create_op =  ops.Graph.create_op
  op_list = []
  def new_create_op(graph_object, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types=None, name=None, attrs=None, op_def=None, compute_shapes=True, compute_device=True):
    # todo: remove keyword args
    op = old_create_op(graph_object, op_type=op_type, inputs=inputs, dtypes=dtypes, input_types=input_types, name=name, attrs=attrs, op_def=op_def, compute_shapes=compute_shapes, compute_device=compute_device)
    op_list.append(op)
    return op
  ops.Graph.create_op = new_create_op
  yield op_list
  ops.Graph.create_op = old_create_op
```